# Improving QuickSort Algorithm with pivot as first element

Tags: algorithms, quicksort

I was trying to improve the algorithm since its the most effective and known algorithm among many others, I came across " Quicksort algorithm with an early exit for sorted subfiles 1987 by University of Tulsa, Roger L. Waiwright" check it out its interesting, do you guys know any other ways/researches ?
I think reducing the memory would work by reducing the amount of arrays and working on one array idk how I am going to do that.

doing bubble sort or selection sort for large arrays isn't helpful and checking if a big array is sorted using them would increase the complexity.
P.S: I am just learning and studying not doing a research etc.

*[Quicksort algorithm with an early exit for sorted subfiles](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/322917.322946)*

Comment: Already ten years ago, python used a different algorithm, timsort (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517347/about-pythons-built-in-sort-method)); not sure what it is using now. It's a misconception that quicksort is the most effective algorithm known.

Comment: You'd also look at what arrays usually look like that are going to be sorted. If you make assumptions about the data, and these assumptions are right, you may end up a lot faster. If these assumptions are often right, and it's very fast to check when the assumption is wrong, you can be faster on average.